# Mysql temp files fill up all partition space

Tags: mysql, joomla

Recently I upgrade my Joomla from 2.5 to 3.7. when I want to login to admin area the following queries make mysql server to create tmp files in /tmp/systemd-private-892fe639aa3041caaa41cc1961ebabf3-mysqld.service-xN1K0r/tmp/#sql_1ea9_0.MAD with with 20 GB of data.

Query 1 :

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.created, a.hits,l.title AS language_title, l.image AS language_image,uc.name AS editor,ag.title AS access_level,c.title AS category_title,ua.name AS author_name FROM qpcgw_content AS a LEFT JOIN `qpcgw_languages` AS l ON l.lang_code = a.language LEFT JOIN qpcgw_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN qpcgw_viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access LEFT JOIN qpcgw_categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid LEFT JOIN qpcgw_users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by ORDER BY a.hits DESC LIMIT 5
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.access, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, a.featured, a.state,l.title AS language_title, l.image AS language_image,uc.name AS editor,ag.title AS access_level,c.title AS category_title,ua.name AS author_name FROM qpcgw_content AS a LEFT JOIN `qpcgw_languages` AS l ON l.lang_code = a.language LEFT JOIN qpcgw_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN qpcgw_viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access LEFT JOIN qpcgw_categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid LEFT JOIN qpcgw_users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5
```

It takes several minutes for disk space getting full and the internal server error appear on user screen.
I find the the problem is because of the order by statement at the end of queries. when I remove that part the query execute in less than a second. I should mentioned that I add index for created and hists in qpcgw_contents tables but the issue didn't resolved.

I appreciate If anybody can help me fix the problem.

Comment: Please try di fix database to your last joomla version. If you can't enter to admin area you can open phpmyadmin of your database and import sql file of your version present in: Joomla_3.7.2-Stable-Update_Package\administrator\components\com_admin\sql\updates

Comment: I did that but unfortunately problem didn't resolve.

Comment: How many row content you have? This query is not important, are only for statistic in admin area, you can remove them.

Comment: There are more that 120 K rows in contents table. I know that this queries aren't important, but is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: You can take a look of this article per performance your type of query: https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/ or simple try to filter something with adding some condition in  where clause